# Given rows and cols, print a list of all seats in a theater

Tags: python

Sample input:

```
2
3
```

Expected output:

```
1A 1B 1C 2A 2B 2C
```

Current code:

```py
num_rows = int(input())
num_cols = int(input())

k='A'

for i in range(num_rows):
    for j in range(num_cols):
        print(f'{i+1}{k}',end=' ')
        k = chr(ord(k)+1)
```

Current output:

```
1A 1B 1C 2D 2E 2F
```

The letter does not start again at "A" for each row.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Instead of taking care of `k`, you can just use `j` to do it: `print(f'{i+1}{chr(ord("A")+j)}',end=' ')`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have misplaced the `k='A'` line. The rest seems to be correct.

```py
num_rows = int(input())
num_cols = int(input())

for i in range(num_rows):
    k='A'
    for j in range(num_cols):
        print(f'{i+1}{k}',end=' ')
        k = chr(ord(k)+1)
```

For your input this would output

```
1A 1B 1C 2A 2B 2C
```